# Java Can Variables Be Used in Variable Names

Tags: java, variables

I have this little script repeated below in my code a few times. I know that I could run a function to do this easily, but can I use a variable as a variable name like in PHP.

```
   if (4val != null && 4val.length() > 0){
            Button 4 = new Button(this);
            4.setText(4val);
            4.setTextSize(20);
        }
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
i=1;
while{i > 10}{
    $$i = value;
    //do stuff with $$i
    i++;
}
```

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: Is your intention to have access to those variables after the loop is done? And why wouldn't you use some sort of collection construct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Map` instead

```
map.put("key","val");    
map.get("key");
```

Well you can also use `array`, `List` , but if you use `HashMap` you retrieval process would be almost o(1)

Comment: The retrieval process will be almost O(1). As opposed to an actual array, when it will be actually O(1)?

Answer (score 5):

No.  But you can stick the buttons in an array, and then iterate through.

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[10];
// instantiate all the buttons
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   // update the button
}
```